# How to do integration test with EFcore to verify that added entity is invalid?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, validation, xunit, ef-core-3.1

I trying to create an integration test and I want to verify that the entity cannot be added.. Sorta like in MVC you have Model.IsValid.. How can I do this ?

```
[Fact]
public async Task Create_Invalid_RfReport_No_FormId()
{
    RfReport existingRr1 = RfReport.Create(1, 1, 1, 1, null, "fn1", "omb1", "des1", "pur1", "back1", "rp1", "freq1", "pr1", true, "cb1", DateTime.Now, "ss1", null);

    try
    {
        _pwdrsRunContext.RfReports.Add(existingRr1); //doesnt add because
        //  entity.Property(e => e.FormId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        // but not an exception. How do I verify context is invalid ? 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Execute `_pwdrsRunContext.SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: But how would I get details of the from the fluent validation that something specific is invalid ?  I ended up skipping this and just doing the test on the web layer using since I can just do Model.IsValid and it returns the details there.